# Weyl Chambers of $ B_2$

Tags: root-systems

> How many Weyl Chambers/bases does $ B_2$ have?

I thought it was 8, but if instead of for bases using obtuse root pairs you use orthogonal pairs, you get 8 different chambers intersect partially with the chambers associated with obtuse pairs.

This also happens with $ G_2$.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the type $B_{2}$ corresponds to Lie algebra $\mathcal{so}(3)$. Its Weyl group should have order $$2\times 6=12$$
as it should be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\rtimes S_{3}$. So the Weyl chamber should have equally many chambers.

Comment: But can Weyl chambers intersect?

Comment: I do not think they would intersect.

Comment: There's something strange I found. Say for $ B_2$ you choose an orthogonal pair of simple roots: find the chamber their hyperplanes enclose, which is eachother. Then say take one of those roots and create a new base with that root and one obtuse to it. Find their chamber enclosed by their hyperplanes and notice that these two chambers intersect.

Comment: To be honest, I do not really know what you are talking about. You should be able to construct the Weyl chambers yourself. In my past experience I never had this happened. And I do not think this would happen to $\mathcal{so}(3)$.

Comment: Ah, I got. I just realized I wasn't considering one of the axioms for simple roots to be considered a base.  The all coefficients must be the same sign axiom.

Comment: I think the order of the Weyl group of type $B_2$ is $8$, and it is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$......